# "I gave her a flower" vs "I gave a flower to her"

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if my understanding is correct.

I learned that the known comes before the unknown.  Therefore, in

A) I gave her a flower.

"her" is the known word and "a flower" is the unknown one, which makes this sentence the answer to the question "What did you give her?"

On the other hand, in

B) I gave a flower to her.

"a flower" is the known one, which makes the sentence the answer to "Who did you give a flower to?"

Is my understanding correct?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "unknown." You posted [a different question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301050/who-did-you-give-the-present-vs-who-did-you-give-the-present-to) about word order in a sentence that asks "who?"; in that situation there is an "unknown." Maybe you meant for these sentences to be similar?

Comment: In the question "what did you give her?", you don't know what the person gave her.  Therefore, "the flower" is unknown.  In "Who did you give the flower?", you don't know who the person gave the flower to.  So, "her" is unknow.

Comment: Thanks; I see now that you mentioned the questions after the examples. It might be nice to edit to mention, at the start, that these are answers to questions.

Comment: I find it natural and easily understood either way. Could be a pondial difference -- I'm from Canada.

Answer (score 1):

All of those sentences are natural and easily understood for me, though I suspect it may be different in the UK. I've never heard of any rule that requires the known part to come first.

In fact, if someone asked me "Who did you give a flower to?" *or* "What did you give to Lucy?", my natural answer in either case would be, "I gave Lucy a flower". I believe it's because it's much more natural to put the indirect object before the direct object. "I gave a flower to Lucy" sounds a bit stilted, like someone learning the language, or poetic, like in song lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. If you reversed the order...

"Who did you give a flower to?"
"I gave Lucy a flower."

...then you wouldn't confuse the questioner; your answer would be understood. But the orders you propose would be the most natural.